# Performance degradation if loop count is not known at compile time on Xeon Phi

Tags: c++, c++11, intrinsics, xeon-phi

I am creating a simple matrix multiplication procedure, operating on the Intel Xeon Phi architecture.

After many attempts with autovectorization, trying to get better performances, I had to use Intel Intrinsics.

Until now, the matrix size was given by a #define in the source code, but when I try to give it at run time, I have a huge performance degradation.

The source code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <mmintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>  // SSE
#include <pmmintrin.h>  // SSE2
#include <emmintrin.h>  // SSE3
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <zmmintrin.h>

#define ALIGNMENT 64 
#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 960
#endif

#define vZero(c) {(c) = _mm512_setzero_pd();}  

#define start_time() \
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
/** Shows the elapsed time. See start_time for usage*/
#define elapsed_time(STRING) \
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start; \
    long long microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count(); \
    printf(#STRING":%lld\n", microseconds);

void recTranspose(double *__restrict__ a, double *__restrict__ aT, const int n, const int k, const int lda, const int ldat){
    if (n*k <= 128) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                aT[j*ldat+i] = a[i*lda+j];
            }
        }
        //printf("Reached _|_");
        return;
    }
    if(k > n) {
        recTranspose(a, aT, n, (k+1)/2, lda, ldat);
        recTranspose(&a[(k+1)/2], &aT[(k+1)/2*ldat], n, k-((k+1)/2), lda, ldat);
    } else {
        recTranspose(a, aT, (n+1)/2, k, lda, ldat);
        recTranspose(&a[(n+1)/2*lda], &aT[(n+1)/2], n- (n+1)/2, k, lda, ldat);
    }

}
/** Calculates 8 cols and 30 rows of c.*/
inline void eightbythirty(double *__restrict__ a, double *__restrict__ b, double * __restrict__ c, const int size) {
    __m512d c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9;
    __m512d c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, c17, c18, c19;
    __m512d c20, c21, c22, c23, c24, c25, c26, c27, c28, c29;


    vZero(c0);  vZero(c1);  vZero(c2);  vZero(c3);  vZero(c4);  vZero(c5);
    vZero(c6);  vZero(c7);  vZero(c8);  vZero(c9);  vZero(c10); vZero(c11);
    vZero(c12); vZero(c13); vZero(c14); vZero(c15); vZero(c16); vZero(c17);
    vZero(c18); vZero(c19); vZero(c20); vZero(c21); vZero(c22); vZero(c23);
    vZero(c24); vZero(c25); vZero(c26); vZero(c27); vZero(c28); vZero(c29);

    __assume_aligned(a, ALIGNMENT);
    __assume_aligned(b, ALIGNMENT);
    __assume_aligned(c, ALIGNMENT);
    __assume(size%16==0);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        const __m512d bv = _mm512_load_pd(b+i*size);
        c0 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+0, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c0);
        c1 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+1, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c1);
        c2 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+2, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c2);
        c3 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+3, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c3);
        c4 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+4, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c4);
        c5 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+5, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c5);
        c6 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+6, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c6);
        c7 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+7, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c7);
        c8 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+8, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c8);
        c9 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+9, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c9);
        c10 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+10, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0),bv, c10);
        c11 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+11, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0),bv, c11);
        c12 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+12, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c12);
        c13 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+13, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c13);
        c14 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+14, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c14);
        c15 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+15, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c15);
        c16 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+16, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c16);
        c17 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+17, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c17);
        c18 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+18, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c18);
        c19 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+19, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c19);
        c20 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+20, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c20);
        c21 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+21, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c21);
        c22 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+22, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c22);
        c23 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+23, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c23);
        c24 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+24, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c24);
        c25 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+25, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c25);
        c26 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+26, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c26);
        c27 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+27, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c27);
        c28 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+28, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c28);
        c29 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(_mm512_extload_pd(a+i*size+29, _MM_UPCONV_PD_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST_1X8, 0), bv, c29);
    }

    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+0*size, c0);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+1*size, c1);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+2*size, c2);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+3*size, c3);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+4*size, c4);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+5*size, c5);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+6*size, c6);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+7*size, c7);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+8*size, c8);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+9*size, c9);

    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+10*size, c10);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+11*size, c11);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+12*size, c12);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+13*size, c13);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+14*size, c14);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+15*size, c15);

    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+16*size, c16);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+17*size, c17);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+18*size, c18);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+19*size, c19);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+20*size, c20);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+21*size, c21);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+22*size, c22);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+23*size, c23);

    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+24*size, c24);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+25*size, c25);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+26*size, c26);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+27*size, c27);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+28*size, c28);
    _mm512_storenr_pd(c+29*size, c29);
}



int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
#ifdef SIZES
    const int size = SIZE;

#else
    const int size = atoi(argv[1]);
#endif
    void* p = malloc((sizeof(double)*5*size*size) + ALIGNMENT-1);
    double *__restrict__ a = (double*)(((size_t)p + ALIGNMENT-1) / ALIGNMENT * ALIGNMENT);
    double *__restrict__ aT = (double*) a+size*size;
    double *__restrict__ b = aT+size*size;
    double *__restrict__ c = b+size*size;
    double *__restrict__ d = c+size*size;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            a[i*size+j] = (double) (rand()%20);
        }
        for(int j2=0; j2<size; j2++){
            c[i*size+j2] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            b[i*size+j] = (double) (rand()%20);
        }
    }


    start_time();
    recTranspose(a, aT, size, size, size, size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+=30) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j+=8) {
            eightbythirty(&aT[i], &b[j], &c[i*size+j], size);
        }
    }
    elapsed_time();
    double gflops = 2.0*size*size*size*1.0e-03/(microseconds);
    printf("Gflops: %f\n", gflops);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            double s = 0;
            for(int u = 0; u < size; u++) {
                s += a[i*size+u] * b[u*size+j];
            }
            d[i*size+j] = s;
        }
    }

    int error = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if(abs(c[i*size+j] - d[i*size+j]) > 1) {
                printf("Error at %d %d , %f instead of %f\n", i, j, c[i*size+j], d[i*size+j]);
                error++;
                if(error > 16) return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("OK\n");

}
```

So for example, having size 960 (for now it works only with sizes multiples of 30*8):

- if I compile with compile time given size: icc -mmic -O3 -restrict -std=c++11 -DSIZES -DSIZE=960 mmul.cpp -o mmul.o

  Elapsed time: 0.460745s
  Gflops: 3.840458
- if I compile with runtime given size: icc -mmic -O3 -restrict -std=c++11 mmul.cpp -o mmul.o

  Elapsed time: 2.204564s
  Gflops: 0.802640

I'm thinking it could be a prefetching issue with icc that can't recognize the memory access pattern. Looking at the generated asm source, the number of vprefetch instructions is much more higher in the "compile time" version.

Funny fact: the check for the correct result of the multiplication (the two for loops at the end of the code, rows 178-197) is much more slower in the compile time version!

Any thoughts? I tried the #pragma loop_count but it seems it's useless, also doing manual intrinsic prefetching doesn't seem to be very effective.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Regards,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of computer science states that any problem can be solved with another layer of indirection.

The idea is to leave leave your code as fixed size loops, and write code to dispatch to the right fixed size loop.

First change `eightbythirty` to read like this:

```
template<int size>
inline void eightbythirty(double *__restrict__ a, double *__restrict__ b, double * __restrict__ c) {
```

with the IDENTICAL implementation inside.  You could put this in `namespace details` as it isn't meant to be user-facing usually.

Next, wrap it:

```
inline void eightbythirty(double *__restrict__ a, double *__restrict__ b, double * __restrict__ c, const int size_divided_by_240) {
  int size=size_divided_by_240;
  switch( size&7 ) {
    case 0: break;
    case 01: eightbythirty<01>(a,b,c); break;
    case 02: eightbythirty<02>(a,b,c); break;
    case 03: eightbythirty<03>(a,b,c); break;
    case 04: eightbythirty<04>(a,b,c); break;
    case 05: eightbythirty<05>(a,b,c); break;
    case 06: eightbythirty<06>(a,b,c); break;
    case 07: eightbythirty<07>(a,b,c); break;
  }
  a+=(size&7)*8*30;
  b+=(size&7)*8*30;
  c+=(size&7)*8*30;
  switch( (size>>3)&7 ) {
    case 0: break;
    case 01: eightbythirty<1*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 02: eightbythirty<2*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 03: eightbythirty<3*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 04: eightbythirty<4*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 05: eightbythirty<5*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 06: eightbythirty<6*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 07: eightbythirty<7*8>(a,b,c); break;
  }
  a += (size&(7<<3))*8*30;
  b += (size&(7<<3))*8*30;
  c += (size&(7<<3))*8*30;
  switch( (size>>6)&7 ) {
    case 0: break;
    case 01: eightbythirty<1*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 02: eightbythirty<2*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 03: eightbythirty<3*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 04: eightbythirty<4*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 05: eightbythirty<5*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 06: eightbythirty<6*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    case 07: eightbythirty<7*8*8>(a,b,c); break;
    default:
  }
  a += (size&(7<<6))*8*30;
  b += (size&(7<<6))*8*30;
  c += (size&(7<<6))*8*30;
  int steps = size/8/8/8;
  for( int i = 0; i < steps; ++i ) {
    eightbythirty<512>(a+512*i, b+512*i, c+512*i);
  }
}
```

This breaks your input size into 3 bit chunks.  It then invokes the fixed-size implementations.  4 branches occur in the above code, much of which are simple jump tables, for values less than 512*8*30.  For values greater than that, things are done mostly in chunks of 512*8*30.

7*3+1 = 22 implementations of your original function are implemented, each with a constant `size`, so the compiler can fully optimize them.

This can be done generically with metaprogramming, but isn't worth it for a one-off use.

I may be missing some `*(8*30)` in the above code when I call the `<int size>` version of `eightbythirty`.

Comment: `The fundamental theorem of computer science states that any problem can be solved with another layer of indirection`. Except for the the problem of too many indirections ;)

Comment: lol :) anyway I flagged "accept" to this answer because using the same technique (but not the exactly same code) it kinda solved my problem. The only remaining issue is that there's a maximum size after that I can't run the program. Unfortunately my submission is very near, so I can't show you right now all the changes in the code. When I'll find some time in the next few days I'll clarify more what I'm doing (always assuming anyone is interested :P)

Answer (score 1):

To check if it is a prefetch optimization result, you can try and compile the version where you define the size with:

```
icc -mmic -O3 -restrict -std=c++11 -no-opt-prefetch -DSIZES -DSIZE=960 mmul.cpp -o mmul.o
```

This will disable the software prefetch insertions. It's a reasonable assumption, since knowing the dataset size will allow for much more efficient prefetching.

If your problem is prefetching, you should try a more aggressive **[compiler option](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/)** **-opt-prefetch=4**. Another idea would be using **#pragma prefetch**. See **[here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/)** for more info.

Did you also try #pragma loop_count. Check **[here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/)**.

You could profile your code with vTune and check your L1 cache hit ratio. It should be very high for a matrix multiplication. Also make sure you use cache blocking.

I'd also recommend running your benchmark using a high number of iterations. That will cover cache warm-up.

Another suggestion from my side would be using math libraries for this task. I see your code is single core, so that will lead to a ~250 GFLOPS performance on all cores. That would be around 25-30% efficiency which is not very good. *Using MKL would give much higher efficiency*.

However, for educational purpose, this exercise is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Yes, cutting down the prefetching the performances collapse (4.310070 s, 0.410544 GFLOPS). But I've no idea how to run the program with user defined size and obtain good performances.

An higher number of iterations doesn't seem to make any difference.

About running it on all cores, sadly the scalability isn't at his best so I get about 210 GFLOPS (238 threads), but there's another story...

And of course, as you guessed, this is for educational purpose, so I can't use math libraries.

Comment: Did you try -opt-prefetch=4. Added this info in my post as well.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also posted at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/534856. The responses at software.intel.com is from a different set of experts.

Comment: Yes I hope is not a problem. I posted also the asm source code there, but instead of searching a workaround like here I'm trying to understand if there are problem with the Intel compiler.

Comment: Posting to both communities is great! More eyes on the problem. It's also good to make sure interested parties know about the other threads. :-)